# trying to import .css files from src/css/style.css in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/css/responsive.css' in 'C:\Users\tanee\Desktop\responsive-pediatric\src'

how to import .css files from folder in reactjs

Comment: Please provide some code how you try to import your css file, and include your folder strutcture too, so we could see where the problem is in your import.

Comment: It might be just that you try to reach for the file too high is file-tree

Comment: import './src/css/style.css';
 import './src/css/responsive.css'

Comment: trying in this way

Comment: Provide better Insights.
Kindly edit your Post and add some code. and references as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't judge correctly since information is not enough but , It seems that you are entering relative path incorrectly.

So change you path statement
From: `./src/css/responsive.css`
To : `./css/responsive.css`

And also in the title you specified that '/src/css/style.css' but in the description you specified '/src/css/responsive.css' , so take care of that too.